# Primefaces - commandButton does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am facing a problem with commandButton, it is working only when the type is submit. Can someone take a look and let me know if there is a solution for that? The code below is very simple and does have the the propose to illustrate what I need. The method test() is not executed. Method runSubmit is executed successfully.

I need that test method is executed without a submit as the original page does have validations that are executed during the submit, test() method must be executed without a submit as it is a preliminary operation before of the submit.

I am using PrimeFaces 4.0, JDK 7, Tomcat 6 and JSF 2.0 (Apache), however I think it is happening in Mojarra as well.

```
    SESSION:

package com.andre.bean;

public class AndreBean {

public void runSubmit() {
System.out.println("Submit executed");
}

public String test() {
System.out.println("Not submit executed");
return "true";
}

}
```

---

```
XHTML

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head> 
</h:head>

<h:form id="test">
<p:commandButton id="ns" value="not submit" type="button" action="#{andreBean.test}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton id="s" value="submit" action="#{andreBean.runSubmit}"></p:commandButton>

</h:form> 

</html>
```

---

Thank you very much
Andre

Comment: try with actionListener="#{andreBean.test()}" process="@this :test" ..

Comment: Thanks for your response, just tried and didn't work, same result as before. However, I am got a parsing error when use parenthesis in the test method, works only with "andreBean.test". I read something that is some limitation related with EL, I need to use Tomcat version 6 in this project so EL available is up to 2.1. Thanks in advance for additional information.

Comment: If you do not want a full form submit you'll have to use AJAX...

Comment: I think I have a restriction because I need to use Tomcat 6. When I use parenthesis in my method (andreBean.test()) I got a parsing error and when I remove the parenthesis I receive a message saying that property "test" does not exist in "andreBean"...deadlock :( I have used ajax in the commandButton as below using parenthesis and not using:
      <f:ajax execute="@form" listener="#{andreBean.test}" />  Some other suggestion?

Comment: You don't need the f:ajax. You can set ajax="true" (which is the default) on the p:commandButton and then use actionListener="#{andreBean.test}"

Comment: It works only if the button type is submit (which is the default as well), with type="button" it does not work. I just run the same test but now using tomcat 7 and JSF 2.2, using that f:ajax execute worked, using parenthesis in the method "#{andreBean.test()}". But Tomcat 7 is not my requirement...it is looking like there is some bug in JSF 2.0 for that. Still thinking a way to fix it using tomcat 6 and JSF 2.0

Comment: Just sharing the information on how to fix this my issue: "<p:commandButton type='button' in combination with a <p:remoteCommand. see user guide.

or <p:commandButton immediate="true" with no type attribute." from [link] (http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34788) Thank everyone that helped me on that.

Answer (score 37):

#### What's going on?

What you get is correct behaviour. In PrimeFaces button with *type="button"* works as it does in basic HTML - it doesn't cause any request. As [PrimeFaces user's guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) says:

> Push buttons are used to execute custom javascript **without causing an
>   ajax/non-ajax request**. To create a push button set type as "button".
>
> ```
> <p:commandButton type="button" value="Alert" onclick="alert('Prime')" />
> ```

If you want to "talk to" bean, you need to use *type="submit"* (which is default in p:commandButton).
However... contrary to submit buttons behaviour in HTML, in PrimeFaces such submission will not force redirection to new page but all communication will be handled by underlying AJAX requests.

Therefore only your second button will execute beans' method:

```
<p:commandButton id="s" value="submit" action="#{andreBean.runSubmit}" />
```

#### What probably you wanted to obtain?

If you don't want to send all your form to bean you can limit the scope of components that are processed with "process" attribute of p:commandButton:

```
<h:form id="test">
    <p:inputText value="#{andreBean.value}"/>
    <p:commandButton id="s" value="submit" action="#{andreBean.runSubmit}" process="@this" />
</h:form>
```

With the following bean you will see the difference:

```
public class AndreBean {

    private String value;

    public void runSubmit() {
        System.out.println("Submit executed");
    }

    public String getValue() {
        System.out.println("getValue");
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        System.out.println("setValue: " + value);
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

If you don't limit executed components in console you get:

```
getValue

setValue: foobar

Submit executed
```

...and with components limited only to *process="@this"* you get only:

```
Submit executed
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have solved my issue using the suggestion at this link [link] (http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=34788) where <p:commandButton immediate="true" worked for me. Many thanks.

Comment: I was getting the similar issue and the process tag works. It was initially set to @this but then I add all my component id's so it would look like this, 
process=@this, componentId1, componentId2  
this changes just works for me, and I didn't added the immediate=true flag t00

Answer (score 15):

Sometimes, the solution is simply add `immediate="true"`, it changes the point, in JSF lifecyle, in which the bean action is triggered.

- Here are an article about how and when use it:
  [immediate attribute article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html)

Comment: it works because you were hitting some validations that you don't see as long as you did not but any p:messages in your code.now when you added immediate=true you are bypassing validations and submitting.

Answer (score -5):

Please check your binding with bean.

bean fields should be String or non primitive.