# Can't show a primefaces panel with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to show a p:panel with a `widgetVar` and `onclick` but it only shows up for like a split second. Then it hides again.
When it hides again I get the following error-message in the browser development console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
```

The error also shows up only for a split second.

This is my .xhtml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html   xmlns  ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
        <h:outputScript name="jquery/jquery.js" library="primefaces"/>  
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="testbutton" ajax="false" onclick="PF('panelwv').show();" />
            <p:panel widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false" toggleable="true">
                <h:outputText value="Test" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>                   
</html>
```

I'm using Primefaces 5.2.

Comment: jquery.js is automatically included. No need to add it manually. Does the error go away when you remove the `h:outputScript`?

Comment: No the problem still remains.

Comment: By 'accident' multiple versions of the PF jar in your webap?

Comment: oh wait... you do `ajax=false`... That is very illogical. You open the panel and then fully refresh the page. Maybe `ajax=false` and not having any action/actionListener causes this. I think you need to add `type='button'` to the`p:commandButton` in this case

Comment: No everything is fine. I got only primefaces-5.2.jar in my webapp.

Comment: You're right! type="button" did the trick. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This is all in the docs... See page 112 of the PF 5.2 docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `ajax="false"` on a `p:commandButton` while not having specified an `action` or `actionListener` attribute referencing a bean, causes this. It looks like you do not need to or do not want to call any action on the server and just do some javascript. In that case add a `type="button"` to the `p:commandButton`.

**See also**:

- [Primefaces - commandButton does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737674/primefaces-commandbutton-does-not-work)
- Page 112 of the [PF 5.2 docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf)