# Reset DropDown,check box in primefaces not working?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

**DropDown Box code:**

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="user" value="#{daywise_Count.selectuserId}" style="width:120px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{daywise_Count.getAllLoginIds()}"                                            var="uif" itemLabel="#{uif.loginId}" itemValue="#{uif.userId} " />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**CheckBox code:**

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="checkbox" value="#{deptBean.checkboxvalue}" /> With All Details
```

**reset function:**

```
function resetter()
{
    document.getElementById('myForm:myMenu_label').innerHTML = 'All';

}
```

**Calling Reset Function**

```
    <h:commandButton id="btnReset" value="Reset" update="myForm" onclick="resetter();" 
styleClass="button" type="submit"> 
</h:commandButton>
```

I am using reset button in myForm that functionality is not working properly  in primefaces.please suggest any solution...

Comment: what does 'not working' mean? Crash? Errors? WW3?

Comment: after clicked reset button same value showing in dropdown and checkbox ...

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the right Dom functions/setters? Is `.innerHTML` correct in resetting the checkbox? I'm almost sure in SO there are questions on setting the value of a checkbox from javascript. Check that. Same for the selectOneMenu

Comment: Please use the preview functionality... And check it... Code you added is not visible... and you can remove the comments above with the code...

Comment: The `h:commandButton` has some peculiarities. The `update="myForm"` attribute is from a `p:commandButton` when ajax is used and does not do anything on an `h:commandButton`. The `type="submit"` is very rarely used in JSF (can't remember ever using it myself ). So maybe you wanted to use a `p:commandButton`? But still then, this is only client-side so maybe you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737674. And can't you reset everything in a different way?

Comment: And please debug what actually happens... server roundtrip wise... I think you will learn a lot

Comment: you should try this <p:commandButton id="btnReset" value="Reset" update="myForm" process="@this"  /> , In update you need to provide your panel id and no need to java script. hope, it will work

Comment: If i am using <p:commandButton> first time only data refreshed and next time not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try this `<p:commandButton id="btnReset" value="Reset" update="myForm" process="@this" />` this is working for me, I hope it will help you too. and no need to java script.

**update="myForm"** attribute means it will update your panel because here you will use panel id and **process="@this"** means it will execute same content after click on reset button for further details you can search on google or refer this link [What is the function of @this exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699088/what-is-the-function-of-this-exactly)